# Pyspark Chi Squared function returns multiple p-values?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using the line of code

```
from pyspark.ml import ChiSquareTest
x = ChiSquaredTest.test(features_df, 'features', 'label')
```

to run a chi squared test. The result is a row with multiples of everything.  I thought there should only be a single p-value returned?

```
Row(pValues=DenseVector([0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15]), degreesOfFreedom = [1,1,1,1,1], 
statistics=DenseVector([2,2,2,2,2]))
```

Why are there multiples of everything and are there instances where these will not all be the same number?  What do I do then?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [the documentation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fc6af9d900ec6f6a1cbe8f987857a69e6ef600d1/python/pyspark/ml/stat.py#L30-L32) it conducts (emphasis mine):

> Pearson's independence test *for every feature* against the label. For each feature,
>      the (feature, label) pairs are converted into a contingency matrix for which the Chi-squared
>       statistic is computed. All label and feature values must be categorical.

So the output vectors are of the shape as `featuresCol`.